# How to update existing and create new form fields in laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a form that saves structured data into sections and i came up with a tricky situation when i want to edit these fields. The form has dynamic fields, so you can add any amount of sections and fields inside each section.
I have a main table which stores "Routines" which can have multiple "sections" and those can have multiple entries of "exercises".
Right now my solution is to delete the current entries and save everything as a completely new routine.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->routines()->whereId($id)->delete();


        $requestArr = $request->all();
        $routine = new Routine();
        $routine->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $routine->name = $requestArr['name'];
        $routine->description = $requestArr['description'];
        $routine->save();

        $routine_id = $routine->id;

        foreach($requestArr['sections'] as $item){
            $section = new Section();
            $section->name = $item['name'];
            $section->description = $item['description'];
            $section->routine_id = $routine_id;
            $section->save();

            $section_id = $section->id;

            if( array_key_exists( 'exercises', $item ) ){
                foreach($item['exercises'] as $item2){
                    $exercise = new Exercise();
                    $exercise->name = $item2['name'];
                    $exercise->description = $item['description'];
                    $exercise->duration = 60;
                    $exercise->duration_unit = 'seconds';

                    $section->exercises()->save($exercise);
                }
            }
        }

        return redirect('/routines');
    }
```

Im sure there is a more "elegant" way of doing this.

My migrations:
Routines:

```
Schema::create('routines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Sections:

```
   Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('routine_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('routine_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('routines')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Exercises:

```
Schema::create('exercises', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->integer('duration');
    $table->string('duration_unit');

    $table->timestamps();


});
```

Routines - one to Many - Sections
Sections - many to many - Exercises (i have a exercise_section middle table)

So my question is, how can i update entries without deleting current ones? Since in case some new sections/exercises get added only those inserts should happen, rest just ->update();

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple strategies you could implement to achieve this. Recreating the entries instead of updating them is a really expensive task, which could produce bottlenecks on your service depending on the activity.

For example, it's possible to determine which fields should be updated on a `routine` entry with some `if` clauses to check if some value is "dirty" (Even Eloquent provides [some methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#updates) which could help you on this).

For the subsequent related entries (section and exercises) you'll need to implement a strategy which involves both back and front-end. For example, if the `update` method is receiving new and existing `sections` you could evaluate which didn't have an id to determine which need to be created.

However this is one of many strategies which could be implemented to avoid recreating the entries. It may looks like too many comparisons, but it results in a less expensive workload compared to recreating all of the entries.

Comment: Yes, this is my main concert as the current implementation is way too "greedy". Just as a thought, is it a good/acceptable pratice to already include some info on the frontend, maybe a extra field with each item in request which can tell existing/new? ir maybe include id's or something similar?

Comment: Although is possible to include some extra field on the frontend, generally is a good practice include the entry id for determine which one is existing/new.